# Transforming a binomial coefficient with Stirling's approximation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am practicing [this problem set](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2020/dc56bd1995baf20cfcdd3fbabdd2dbc9_MIT6_006S20_ps1-questions.pdf), problem 1-1 c).

The [solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-spring-2020/10e4e3444c1bde4c662a47a8f14dadd3_MIT6_006S20_ps1-solutions.pdf) says that using Stirling's approximation, the result is $f_4=\Theta({\frac{6}{5^{5/6}}^n}/\sqrt{n})$.

I managed to translate $n\choose{n/6}$ to:

$$
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n}{e}^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n/6}\frac{n/6}{e}^{n/6} \sqrt{2\pi 5n/6}\frac{5n}{6e}^{5n/6}}
$$

In asymptotic analysis, all constant factors can be dropped. Also, the limit of $(1/c)^n$ is zero for $c > 0$, and $\sqrt{n}$ cancels once, so this remains:

$$
\frac{n^n}{\sqrt{n}n^{n/6}n^{5n/6}}
$$

But how do I continue from there?

Comment: Constant factors on the entire expression can be dropped but you dropped constants that were being hit with exponents which is not allowed.

Comment: But can't I say, e.g.: $(n/e)^n=n^n (1/e)^n$ and then drop the second part? Could you specify which part you refer to?

Comment: No, you can't drop the latter because it isn't actually a constant factor. It is exponentially decaying. Here the $e$'s will cancel but some other exponential terms will not cancel.

Comment: When it's exponentially decaying, it doesn't matter in terms of asymptotic analysis, or does it?

Comment: It does matter. $(n/6)^{n/6}$ grows much slower than $n^{n/6}$ for example.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancellation of $$\frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n/6}\left(\frac{n/6}{e}\right)^{n/6} \sqrt{2\pi 5n/6}\left(\frac{5n/6}{e}\right)^{5n/6}}$$  gives $$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5n\pi/9}\,  \,5^{5n/6}/6^n} = \sqrt{\frac{9}{5 \pi}} \frac{6^n}{5^{5n/6} \sqrt{n}}$$ and you can ignore the constant $\sqrt{\dfrac{9}{5 \pi}}$ for these asymptotic growth purposes, leaving the $\dfrac{6^n}{5^{5n/6} \sqrt{n}}$ term quoted in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to start with
$$\binom{n}{\frac{n}{6}}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{6}+1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{5n}{6}+1\right)}$$ and,  now, apply three times Stirling approximation
$$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{6}+1\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{5 n}{6}+1\right)}\right)=n \left(\log (6)-\frac{5 \log (5)}{6}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{18}{5 \pi
    n}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Now, use $A=e^{\log(A)}$